# How do I break a loop externally in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say this function is running:

```
var runningFunction = "none",
    foo             = 1000,
    counter         = 0;

function someFunc() {

    runningFunction = "someFunc";

    from(var i = 0; i < foo; i++) {

        counter++;

    }

}
```

and I wanted to break that, say upon a window.resize detection

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    // break someFunc function
    // say scenario broke at count = 595

}
```

How can I do that? I can write to some variable which function is running, as shown above.

Comment: Javascript has **run-to-completion** semantics. That means `someFunc` would block everything until returning. If you want non-blocking behavior, look more closely at asynchronous programming, the **event loop** and **preemptive multitasking**.

Comment: @Iven thanks for this, I will read up on that, I need to make this work, otherwise my work will have a known flaw despite that being a language problem.

Comment: Why not just adding a conditional break inside the for loop?: if (ready) { break; }

Comment: @LeonPlata But external code won't be able to change `ready` until the function finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. All the code in the function will run in a block. Other code like resize event listeners will wait until the function has finished.

If you really want to "pause" it, you will need to break it into different functions, and use `setTimeout` to call the next one. This will allow other code to run in the middle.

```js
var timer,
    counter = 0,
    result = document.getElementById('result');
function someFunc() {
  counter++;
  result.textContent = counter;
  if(counter < 1e5) timer = setTimeout(someFunc, 0);
}
someFunc();
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

```html
Counter: <span id="result"></span><button id="stop">Stop counter</button>
```

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to stop animations in order to resize/reposition the elements and then reset the animation... because right now, the elements do not resize because as you guys said, the animation has to finish, and these animations are already broken into segments. But each segment itself can't stop. So then I get these giant/out of place elements.

Comment: Wow this is great, this might be the only solution to this problem, and if so thank you very much. I will try and understand your code, then implement it on my code. Thanks again. I haven't heard of clearTimout until now.

Comment: `clearTimeout` removes a `setTimeout` timer from the queue.

Comment: Sorry to ask you, can you explain this line: the if(counter < 1e5) timer = setTimeoutsomeFunc, 0); what is that? Is that an if statement combined with a variable declaration? I've never seen this before. I get the 1e5 is exponential notation. I don't see an opening bracket after the if(counter < 1e5) not saying it's wrong as obviously it works. Thanks.

Comment: `setTimeout(someFunc, 0)` creates a timer to execute `someFunc` as soon as possible, asynchronously. It returns a timer ID, which is assigned to `timer` variable so that the timer can be cancelled with `clearTimeout`. All of this is wrapped inside an `if` statement, brackets are optional when you have a single statement. Use `if(counter < 1e5) { timer = setTimeout(someFunc, 0); }` if you prefer.

Comment: Wow that's incredible. Thank you for this very much.

Comment: Well I tried to implement this in my code. I didn't get it to work. Not saying your answer is wrong, I think I'm applying it to the wrong situation. In a function I have as many as 7 setTimeouts that run at different times, I tried to have the if statment in there several times, at each point getting a new end time to calculate elapsed time but it broke the progress of the animation. Not your concern, but your solution I think is the way to go I just have to figure out how to do it right. Maybe my setTimeout intervals are redundant with this new setTimeout...

Comment: @joehungjohn Sometimes it's difficult to split a function into asynchronous blocks. You can also try [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Thanks for the tip and your help. I ran into a "too much recursion" error haha interesting haven't had that before.

Comment: I don't suppose there's any chance I could contact you and ask you for your professional opinion? A simple yes or no, after looking at some code? I don't mean to bother you, I just want to know before I waste a lot of time trying random things out if I can accomplish what I'm trying to do based on how I've structured my code/what I'm trying to accomplish.